# common task for Uploading Build Artifacts, Multiple Apps

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, dependencies

I have 5 different apps in my monorepo, the build.gradle for each of these apps contains a nearly indentical task, which along with an upload script is in charge of uploading files matching to our Jenkins file server.

we can call this `task releaseBuilds()`

This code is in a file called `artifactUploads.gradle`, this file also contains a custom plugin called `UploadPlugin`. Now my concern is with the System.out.println() line in the task.

```
apply plugin: UploadPlugin

task copyReleaseBuilds() {
    doLast {
        def dir = project.file('build/outputs/apk')
        dir.eachFileRecurse(FILES) { file ->
            if (file.getName().contains(".apk") && file.getName().contains("release")) {
                System.out.println("uploading ${file.getName()}")
                def rootDir = project.getRootDir().path
                def filePath = file.path
                def fileName = file.name.replace('app-', '')
                exec {
                    workingDir rootDir
                    commandLine "./uploadBuild.sh", filePath, "$dirPath" + fileName
                }.assertNormalExitValue()
            }
        }
    }
}

class UploadPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        //Create container instance for config object
        //plugin stuff
         NamedDomainObjectContainer<Config> configContainer =
            project.container(Config)
    project.extensions.add('directory', configContainer)
    project.task('uploadConfig') << {
        def uploadConfig = project.extensions.getByName('directory')
    }
}

class Config{
    String name
    String dirPath

    Config(final String name){
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

In the `build.gradle` file for each of my apps/projects. I have the line

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/artifactUploads.gradle
```

along with

```
directory{
name{
    dirPath = "hca/"
    println "stuff"
}
```

}

directory is some object that is created in my CustomPlugin.
Now when I build the line `println "Stuff"` is output to the gradle log, however I can not find any console outputs that are put in `artifactUploads.gradle` which contains my CustomPlugin and the task that all my apps share.

From what I understand, since each of my apps `build.gradle` has 
`apply from: artifactUploads.gradle`, each app should now run the `copyReleaseBuilds()` task, with the custom parameter `dirPath` which is set in the DSL part of each app `build.gradle`.

Is there another reason the build would not be hitting that `System.out.println()`? I'm very new to gradle in general so thanks for your help

Comment: What Gradle command do you run? What is the `uploadConfig` task supposed to do, I don’t see it used anywhere?

Comment: So I already answered this question and my answer was deleted for some reason

Comment: What do you mean, you added an answer to _your_ question or you commented on the questions from my previous comment?

Comment: Yes I have already answered the question it does not need answered